# Execute Stored Procedure from another Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to Execute one procedure from another procedure and store specific columns from the result of procedure in a temp table without declaring it but Columns are not known and changes depends on the conditions.

I have tried following code but its not working

```
select * into #Temp1 from Exec(Procedure @parameter)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `store specific columns from the result` and `but Columns are not known and changes depends on the conditions`. Be a bit more clearer.

Comment: Procedure returns Column A, Column B & Column C but i want only Column A or sometimes Column A & Column B in return.

Comment: I guess this can solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table

Answer (score 1):

Use `OPENROWSET` to insert the SP's result into `temp` table

Before using `OPENROWSET` you have to configure `Ad Hoc Distributed Queries`

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

SELECT * INTO #Temp 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=yourservername;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'EXEC Procedure @parameter')

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Comment: i am unable to use OPENROWSET because of security issues. Is there any other way?

Comment: Yes. I'm getting following error. 

SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', search for 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' in SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: @user2148124 Okay contact your DBA. Without knowing the number of returned by SP this is the only way to store the result into temp table.